# Excel VBA delete blank Cells containing ONLY Formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to print an Excel sheet where I have data from another sheet which I get using "=sheet1!cell".
I copied this formula on the entire row but when there is nothing on sheet1 to link on the 2nd sheet, the formula stays in an empty cell.

The problem is, when I print, I have a lot of empty pages because there is still a formula in the "empty" cells.

I tried to make a "TEMP" sheet where I paste the last version of the project and want to print "TEMP" but I don't know how to delete BLANK cells containing only a formula.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try by your own? Do you have these formulae on all the range, or only in a column?

Comment: I have this formulae in the columns A to F

Comment: And what do you wand doing when such a  formula returns an empty string? To delete entire row? To clear the formula? To delete the cell, as you say? If yes, do you understand what dis operation mean? You will ruin all your data if such cells will be deleted and the cell below it will be shifted up...

Comment: The cells I want to empty are at the bottom, so I don't mind cell shifting..

Comment: Then, test the code I  posted and send some feedback.

Comment: the data is filled up to a certain cell in the column and after this cell, the empty cells with the formula as content continue to a certain point. and I want to "delete" (clear the formulae out of the cells) these cells, otherwise they will be printed.

Comment: Do you want to **delete** them or to **clear** their content? I posted a piece of code deleting, as you required. I asked **To clear the formula?**, but you din not confirm that this is what you want. So, can you state what do you need, from this point of view? I can easily adapt the code to only clear the formula, which should be better, in my opinion... Adapted the code to offer the variant you like.

Comment: Sry I didn't read this comment. Yes I want to delete the formulae out of every cell, so there is no formulae anymore.

Comment: How to miss one of only two questions? You answered immediately after it. Anyhow, are there other surprises in your sheet to be processed?

Comment: To do it as simple as possible, I think I only need a code to clear the formulae out of "empty" cells in a specific range. I'm sorry If I annoy you, my english is not the best and I'm at a student job and never saw VBA...

Comment: I tried doing it as simple as possible, but starting from your question **as it has been formulated**. I will adapt the code to also work in merged cells having such a formula. The previous way does not work as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will delete all cells having a formula which returns "":

```
Sub clearFormulaEmptyCells()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngForm As Range, rngDel As Range, cF As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 On Error Resume Next
  Set rngForm = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
 On Error GoTo 0
 If rngForm Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 For Each cF In rngForm.cells      'iterate between cells having formula
    If cF.value = "" Then          'find the ones returning the null strinig      
        If rngDel Is Nothing Then  'if rngDel not Set:
            Set rngDel = cF        'Set it as first such a cell
        Else
            Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, cF) 'make a Union between the existing range and the cell returning a null string
        End If
    End If
 Next
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.ClearContents  'it will clear the formula
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version. It will also clear formula in merged cells:

```
Sub testCleanFormulaMergedCellsInclusive()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngF As Range, A As Range, cel As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
 On Error Resume Next
  Set rngF = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
 On Error GoTo 0
 
 If rngF Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 
 For Each A In rngF.Areas
    For Each cel In A.cells
        If cel.Address <> cel.MergeArea.Address Then
            If cel.value = "" Or cel.value = 0 Then cel.MergeArea.ClearContents
            Exit For
        Else
          If cel.value = "" Or cel.value = 0 Then cel.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It works partly. It unmerges cells and cleans every 2nd column from the formulae. I write in the columns A-F. A,C,E is the data written and B,D,F is the date written, when the data is added. Only B,D,F gets cleaned, the other columns is still the formulae in empty cells

Comment: @Mr. Robot Did you mention anything about merge cells and I missed it?

Comment: @Mr. Robot I edited the above answer and placed a piece of code able to also deal with merged cells. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: This version works better. But now there are "0" in the place, where the formula was and has the same effect when printing.

Comment: @Mr. Robot It shouldn't! This is not standard Excel behavior. Please, remember what settings did you do, in order to make it display 0. Do you mean that all your sheet shows zero in empty cells? What formula bar shows for such a cell? Zero,  nothing, as it should or the formula?

Comment: @Mr. Robot Are you sure that the formulae you are talking about do not return zero? If you have a formula like "=B5" and B5 is empty, **it will not return ""**. **It will return zero!** This is the way Excel works! Is this your case? Should I adapt the code to clear formulae returning "" or "0"?

Comment: Now when I use your code, it clears everything. It clears every cell, where I have my formula with its data. Only the cells, with a string stay..

Comment: I have 2 sheets. I link cells between those two with =Sheet1$A20 to get the data and show it in sheet2

Comment: @Mr. Robot please refresh the page (this one) and use the updated code.

Comment: Now, it clears also formulae returning zero, which is not the same as ""...

Answer (score 0):

The function `=FormulaText()` might be handy for you.

I've created a small Excel sheet:

- In cell A2, there's an empty string.
- In cell B2, there's the formula `=A2`.
- In cell B3, there's the formula `=FormulaText(B2)`

Hereby the result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will help with my problem. I need to empty a blank cell. because the cell is not empty when there is still a formulae inside which causes empty pages when printing.

Comment: ? You can solve your problem, setting the print area. In order to do this according to your wishes, you need to omit the blank cells, containing a formula. For that, you can use the `FormulaText()` worksheet function. How to set print area is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea